# Disable F11 Fullscreen action in terminal by commands or file edition

Tags: ubuntu, lubuntu

Is there any terminal that suports dynamic profile changes by editing a profile file or something? I Need to disable F11. I tried Terminator and QTerminal and day simply ignore the new profile set.

Comment: What is a "dynamic profile change"? Is it enough to use a terminal that doesn't have F11 as a shortcut for full screen? Like `xterm`?

Comment: For my need, I tried xterm, but it didn't work properly.